# Html position multiple blocks

Tags: html, css, css-position, footer

I have a footer that I want to position it on the bottom. Here is my code but it doesn't work. Spans don't align in one line. I have also tried display: inline. But when I do that, spans don't position in the left, center, and right. **Please help me**.

```
<div style="background-color:grey;width:100%;position:fixed;bottom:0px;">
            <div style="text-align:left;margin-left:10px;">
                <span>Site Developer: Mahan Lameie</span>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <span>Copyright© 2020 Mahan Lameie</span>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:right;margin-right:10px;">
                <span>E-mail:mahan.lameie87@gmail.com</span>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="footer" style="background-color:grey;width:100%;position:fixed;bottom:0px;">
            <div style="text-align:left;margin-left:10px;">
                <span>Site Developer: Mahan Lameie</span>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <span>Copyright© 2020 Mahan Lameie</span>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:right;margin-right:10px;">
                <span>E-mail:mahan.lameie87@gmail.com</span>
            </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.footer {
  display : flex;
}

.footer div{
flex-grow : 1
}
```

I add the footer class and add some style for this class.

Comment: The previous answer was the same but I think this would be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

A good way would be to use `flexbox` to get your elements aligned in a row. 
Here is and example, where I added `display: flex;` to your wrapping div, and then added `flex-grow: 1;` to each item to define the ability to grow and take up equal width.

```html
<div style="background-color:grey;width:100%;position:fixed;bottom:0px; display: flex; ">
    <div style="flex-grow: 1; text-align:left;margin-left:10px;">
        <span>Site Developer: Mahan Lameie</span>
    </div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1; text-align:center;">
        <span>Copyright© 2020 Mahan Lameie</span>
    </div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1; text-align:right;margin-right:10px;">
        <span>E-mail:mahan.lameie87@gmail.com</span>
    </div>
</div>
```